# Tengo dudas con las trazas en las base de datos

Tags: java, postgresql, orm

Estoy haciendo un Sistema de Gestión de Base de Datos en **JAVA** utilizando **orm** y me gustaría saber **¿qué se usa para registrar las trazas con la capa de persistencia de la aplicación Java?**. La Base de Datos fue creado en **postgreSQL v9.3**

Comment: La pregunta es un poco amplia tal y como está descrita: ¿te refieres a los ficheros de log de la base de datos, o a de la capa de persistencia de la aplicación Java? Te aconsejo [edit] y especificar un poco más

Comment: Me refiero a la capa de persistencia de la aplicación Java